# Searching for selectors not using document.querySelector/document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a technical interview the other day and failed a certain question:

> > Given a CSS selector (can just be a class name, id or an arbitrary
> >     number of selectors), return the parent DOM element in an array. The caveat is that you cannot use external libraries or use
> >     `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`. Use
> >     the HTML code below:
>
> ```
> <div></div>
> <div id="idOne" class="classOne classTwo"></div>
> <img id="IdTwo" class="classTwo classThree"></img>
> ```

For example, if given a CSS selector of `img.ClassTwo` it would return the `img` tag, where if the given CSS selector was `div#idOne.classTwo` it would return 1 `div`, whereas if the selector was just `div`, it would return 2 `divs`. Whereas if I was given `img#One` it would return an empty array.

My code below works, but I feel that it is too 'cheeky' as it doesn't use either `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` directly, but uses a variation of `document.querySelectorAll` - as I can't think of an alternative method that can cater for an arbitrary number of CSS selectors unlike how `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` can.

Is my code correct? Or can it be improved anyway?

```
var theFunction = function (input) {

    let arr = [];

    let body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];

    let selectors = body.querySelectorAll(input);

    for (i = 0; i < selectors.length; ++i) {
        arr.push(selectors[i].nodeName);
    }

    console.log(arr);

}
```

Comment: The way I understood the question `return the parent DOM element` is that given `<div><img ...></div>` and a selector `img`, it would need to return the `<div>`, i.e. its **parent element**. But with the given example DOM it wouldn't work (or would return whatever the surrounding element actually is, e.g. `<body>`).

Answer (score 3):

Your method doesn't work because it fails to select elements outside the body.

I think what you were supposed to do is:

- split the input into class / ID / tagName (using REGEX or whatever)
- request elements using `document.getElementByID()` / `document.getElementsByClassName()` / `document.getElementsByTagName()`
- return only the elements that match all 3 requests.

Essentially, you code your own `querySelectorAll` function.

Comment: Yeah, I see the logic. But wouldn't that return all CSS selectors? Not the selectors that belong to one HTML element?  EG, if I was given CSS selectors of `img#idOne` that should return an empty array, but if used with your algorithm, it would return true as all CSS selectors exist in the DOM